# Having Trouble Performing a Simple MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to PHP and still learning the basics and I'm stuck on an issue I'm hoping someone could help me with.

I have the following code;

```
$MfgQuery = "SELECT `Mfg` FROM `categories` WHERE `ID` = 10";

if($MfgQueryRun = mysql_query($MfgQuery)) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun)==NULL){
        echo 'No Mfg Results Returned';
    } else {
    $Mfg = $MfgQueryRun['Mfg'];
    echo $Mfg;
}
} else {
echo 'Query Unsuccessful';

}
```

But for a reason unknown to me I keep getting 'No Mfg Results Returned' but if I copy and paste the query by itself into the MySQL box in PHPMyAdmin it returns a result properly.

What gives??

BTW, Here's exactly what I can insert into PHP MyAdmin's SQL box;

```
SELECT `Mfg` FROM `categories` WHERE `ID` = 10
```

and this returns a result but using the code above, it does not.

If anyone wouldn't mind showing me where I went wrong I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance

Comment: Use Mysqli or PDO instead of mysql

Comment: In addition to what @Akam said, you should run mysql_select_db(your_db_name) before your query to be safe. EDIT: Or specify the db name in front of your table name: "Select `Mfg` from `my_db`.`categories`"

Comment: use `if(!mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun)) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: maybe `mysql_fetch_assoc` befor `$Mfg = $MfgQueryRun['Mfg'];`?

Comment: in your example I believe you didn't execute `mysql_fetch_array()`. **BUT:** Don't use `mysql_*` funtions. They are deprecated. use http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. It's not too late to start using proper tools:)

Comment: HI @MiroslavStopka I appreciate the recommendation to move to PDO or MySQLi but for now I'd like to stick with what I'm working with for now, this way I can gain a better understanding of the very basics of PHP and MySql before moving into another language. Plz consider that I just spent the past several months doing nothing but PHP and MySQL tutorials so I'd like to apply some of that knowledge to the point where I better understand the basics (I'm still taking in and don't fully understand paramaters and functions among other functions etc as well)

Comment: @StuartKaufman: PDO and mysqli are NOT new languages, they just better and more advanced tools. `mysql_` won't help you to understand PHP better

Comment: Hi Everyone, I really appreciate everyone's help and I look forward to learning PDO or MySQLi, it's just right now I'm trying to learn the basics but when the time comes form me to transition to PDO I'll have an entire site to convert so that's gonna have to be put on hold for now while I better learn the basics. (The stuff ya'll assume that "Everyone Knows")

Comment: I prefer to write   mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun) < 1   it's a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $MfgQuery = "SELECT `Mfg` FROM `categories` WHERE `ID` = 10";

  $MfgQueryRun = mysql_query($MfgQuery) ;
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($MfgQueryRun) ;

   if (mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun)== 0 ){
    echo 'No Mfg Results Returned';
  } else {
   $Mfg = $row['Mfg'];
   echo $Mfg;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @echo_me I'm stuggling to even work with code this simple but I'll get it and I thank you all for your excellent help.

Comment: Hi @echo_me, YES, You're answer was very helpful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$MfgQuery = "SELECT `Mfg` FROM `categories` WHERE `ID` = 10";
$MfgQueryRun = mysql_query($MfgQuery);

if($MfgQueryRun) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun) == 0){
        echo 'No Mfg Results Returned';
    } else {
    $Mfg = $MfgQueryRun['Mfg'];
    echo $Mfg;
}
} else {
echo 'Query Unsuccessful';

}
```

Comment: change `mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun)> 0` to `mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun)<= 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($MfgQueryRun)){
        echo 'No Mfg Results Returned';
} else {
       $Mfg = $MfgQueryRun['Mfg'];
       echo $Mfg;
}
```

Try this remove the NULL in comparison. because mysql_num_rows returns numeric values.

Comment: numeric values ... or `false` ;-)

Comment: @acme numeric values. as if query returns 5 rows then this function will return 5 not true and false.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated (outdated) as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Use mysqli instead.

Second, you're not testing properly. PHP has no strong types, so a test '== null' does not always do, what you'll expect. See the PHP manual for [comparision operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). To test against **null**, always use **is_null()**.

Third, you're not fetching the data.

Using MySQLi, the code would look similar to this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno != 0) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    die(); // or return, if in method or function context
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Mfg` FROM `categories` WHERE `ID` = 10");
if ($result === false) {
    echo "Query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    die(); // or return, if in method or function context
}

printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['Msg'];

/* free result set */
$result->close();
```